# JSON.NET deserialize custom date format

Tags: c#, .net, json, datetime, json.net

I want to deserialize date like this `"20160101000000000"` to `DateTime` in UTC kind.

```
var data = "20160101000000000";
var dateTime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(data,
            new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyyMMddhhmmssfff"});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```
var data = "20160101000000000";
var dateTime = new DateTime(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Int64>(data));
```

If you want to UTC format, try following

```
var utc = dateTime.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");
```

Or implement Custom Datetime Converter

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
 public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{ return; }

public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
  return new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(reader.Value));
}
```

}

And use like this

```
var data = "20160101000000000";
var dateTime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(data, new CustomDateTimeConverter());
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in JSON, strings must be quoted. Therefore what you've got in `data` is actually *not* a JSON string (it's a number). If you want JSON.NET to parse this the way you expect, you'll need to wrap it in quotes:

```
var data = "\"20160101000000000\"";
```